# how to make geometry shaders in libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I was wondering around on the gpu rendering topic, and I found out that there are Geometry Shaders in Opengl 3. I am currently working on a project in libgdx, and would like to render particles with the gpu, instead of generating the mesh every frame. I looked on every documentation of libgdx but couldn't find anything, I loked up the source code too, and there is nothing too.

I would like to know how I have to proceed to make an implementation of it.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

libGDX is a cross platform library, which also targets mobile platforms like Android and iOS, as well as web browsers using webGL. Therefor it doesn't use OpenGL but instead it uses [OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/) (strictly speaking it does use OpenGL on desktop using LWJGL, but it only provides a subset of it through the GL interfaces). Or to be more specific, it currently mainly targets OpenGL ES 2.x (although it also contains an option to use 3.x).

OpenGL ES doesn't support geometry shaders. So you either would have to use an [extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_geometry_shader.txt) (which might not be available on your target device) or limit yourself to only desktop. In the latter case you'd write all your code in the desktop project in which you'd have access to all LWJGL classes, including its OpenGL wrappers.

Comment: it will be desktop only anyway, this is why I asked for it. I asked for a way to do it... I even looked for it on the lwjgl forums, and It didn't help me. Could you please link me to a website that exlains how to set up the opengl environnement in lwjgl required for this sort of thing? thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not aware of a website that explains how to use geometry shader in lwjgl. If you want an explanation of that then consider asking a new question for that with the lwjgl tag instead of the libgdx tag. As for the libgdx api, it is not possible to use geometry shaders, because opengl es doesnt support them.